# Format Text Field While User Enters Data

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, mask, formatting

so here is what I am trying to do.  I have a birth date text field, while the user in puts text i want the field to automatically put it in the form YYYY-MM-DD.  Basically while the user types it replaces the Y's M's and D's but leaves the hyphen.  I am not sure how to go about this i may need a mask or something.

I know this is where some of the formatting can be done

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{
```

Any help would be of much help

Comment: Why don't you just use the date picker??

Comment: I didn't like how it is set up, plus i am going to be adding things like phone number and such so this is good to know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so here is what i have now

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    //Format Date of Birth YYYY-MM-DD
    if(textField == txtDOB)
    {
        if ((txtDOB.text.length == 4)||(txtDOB.text.length == 7))
            //Handle backspace being pressed
            if (![string isEqualToString:@""])
            txtDOB.text = [txtDOB.text stringByAppendingString:@"-"];
        return !([textField.text length]>9 && [string length] > range.length);
    }
    else
        return YES;

}
```

Only problem is that when i try to back space, it doesn't work my guess is because it is trying to add the dash every time i hit the backspace key.  Anyone know a work around?

Comment: See my answer. You're re-inventing the wheel and getting bitten by the fact.

Answer (score 0):

You want an [NSDateFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html). See also the [Data Formatting Programming Guide for Cocoa](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) (in the iPhone docs).

Comment: Your second link is returning 404