# auto-format decimal text as user enters numbers

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I think I am trying to do something like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3056999/format-text-field-while-user-enters-data), but in a different language.

I have a Textbox that allows for a decimal based number to be entered. I want to eliminate the need for hitting the decimal key. I have the input scope on the textbox set to 'Number', so the user has numbers and a decimal to hit. Here's an example of what I'd like to see:

Initial display:

- 0.00

Tap the number 5:

- 0.05

Tap the number 8:

- 0.58

Then tap 3 - 2:

- 58.32

And if the user hits the delete key:

- 5.83

I'm not sure how to go about this. I'm thinking that the default value of the textbox is 0.00, and in the `OnKeyDown` event, take their number, and set the value appropriately?

Comment: Yep, using the KeyDown event would be the way to do this.

Comment: Another important point is KeyDown doesn't fire when you paste something in. You will also need to listen to TextChanged.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you're almost there.

```
 If the key is a digit, 
  float work = float.tryparse(textbox.value )
  work *= 10; // move decimal
  work += key / 100; // move new digit 2 decimals right
  textbox.value = work.ToString();
```

For backspace, I wouldn't bother with the math, just substring off the last character.

Comment: I will give this a try and see what happens. I'm leaning towards the custom maskedtextbox I linked to in TysHTTP reply.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a MaskedTextBox, with a Mask like this: 00.00 and set RightToLeft to Yes? 
I think you can accomplish just what you need.

Comment: Ow, i didn't see the tag Windows phone 7, i'm not sure whether you can used MaskedTextBox over there.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't think of a MaskedTextBox...It doesn't appear that one exists, but I did find this post on the SL Forums: http://forums.silverlight.net/post/496643.aspx. I'll have to give that custom control a shot.

Comment: Unfortunately, the MaskedTextProvider class isn't resolving in the System.ComponentModel assembly in WP7.